# Getting an undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I am trying to do is record the amount of sleep a user gets, and then be able to display back the median monthly amount of sleep based on a monthly range, as well as a yearly range. The current_user is a helper from devise, and sleep belongs_to user. user has_many sleeps.

Controller:

```
def index
  @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today

  @sleeps = current_user.sleeps
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render action: 'index' }
    format.js
  end

  total_average_sleep_time = Array.new
  @sleeps.each do |average|
    average = average.hours
    total_average_sleep_time.push(average)
  end
  @total_average_sleep_time = median(total_average_sleep_time)

  month_range = current_user.sleeps.where(:sleep_date => @date.beginning_of_month..@date.end_of_month)
  monthly_average_sleep_time = Array.new
  month_range.each do |average|
    average = average.hours
    monthly_average_sleep_time.push(average)
  end
  @monthly_average_sleep_time = median(monthly_average_sleep_time)
end

private

def median(array)
  sorted = array.sort
  len = sorted.length
  return (sorted[(len - 1) / 2] + sorted[len / 2]) / 2.0
end
```

Full error message:

```
Started GET "/sleeps" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-21 18:34:50 -0700
Processing by SleepsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  Sleep Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "sleeps".* FROM "sleeps" WHERE "sleeps"."user_id" = 2
  Rendered sleeps/index.html.erb within layouts/application (17.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 115ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/sleeps_controller.rb:69:in `median'
app/controllers/sleeps_controller.rb:16:in `index'


Rendered /Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (6.6ms)
```

Full Trace:

```
app/controllers/sleeps_controller.rb:69:in `median'
app/controllers/sleeps_controller.rb:16:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__271727191433844250__process_action__1430197560934326917__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3592650198556540672__call__1302268635398135570__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Can anyone explain to me WHY this is happening? It works perfectly in the console. Is there a more clear way to debug issues like this? I know it's due to the addition in the median method, but why?

Comment: This can be generated with the expression: `nil + 10` - so what does it mean? Well, it means that `nil` (of type `NilClass`) is appearing on the *lefthand side* of a binary `+` operator. So find out where and fix it.

Comment: Can you put the whole error message?

Comment: How can it be nil in one place, and not nil in another? The console works, and the controller doesn't.

Comment: Outside just telling you that you have an unexpected nil, you'll have to give some more, a full backtrace, etc.

Comment: I added the full trace, but I don't imagine that is what you're asking for?

Comment: What are you doing in the console?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks you guys, giving me a kick in the ass. I wasn't doing error reporting well enough. Stupid stupid mistake.

@sleeps = current_user.sleeps is returning an empty array... I thought it was returning the same output as Sleep.all... No exception was thrown.

Thanks for spending a second putting me in my place, especially the anon user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `median` method blows up on an empty array, since `sorted[-1]` doesn't exist and thus attempting to retrieve it gives `nil`.

You could put in a guard clause, but there is no sensible value for the median of zero numbers, imo.

Also, on a stylic note `Enumerable#map` is nicer than `#each`ing through and `#push`ing, again imo.

May the Ruby be with you.